# Is there any way i can display specific cell value along with Header and Column Value in using python panda

Tags: python, pandas

Well i am reading table .xls file, 
and calling them in DataFrame.
i am trying to perform  following operation

find specific value  Let Say 3 values  matching  from Column Amount
i need to display it as a table with Header and Rows matching Values in the Cell and Count of those Values, with below code i can display only value

```
Invoice table
123      100
133      200
902      500
987      100
767      100
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'SALES.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('SALES')
a = df1.loc[(df1['AMOUNT'] == 744, 'INVOICE')]
```

I got sofa having only

```
0 100
4 100
5 100
```

I need it to be like

```
Invoice table
123      100
987      100
767      100
```

with count = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = df1[df1['AMOUNT'] == 744]
```

a will return the dataframe you are looking for. The way you wrote it returned a series which is why it looked as it did.

Comment: thanks for Answer, it shows the table with index, any idea how can i avoid Index and get count ?

Comment: ```len(a)``` will give you the length of the filtered DataFrame, which is also the count in this case.